# Sharepoint online display templates don't show custom properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, display-template, managed-property

i defined my properties in display template, this is the generated javascript

```
ctx['DisplayTemplateData']['ManagedPropertyMapping']={'Title':['Title'], 'Path':['Path'], 'Description':['Description'], 'EditorOWSUSER':['EditorOWSUSER'], 'LastModifiedTime':['LastModifiedTime'], 'CollapsingStatus':['CollapsingStatus'], 'DocId':['DocId'], 'HitHighlightedSummary':['HitHighlightedSummary'], 'HitHighlightedProperties':['HitHighlightedProperties'], 'FileExtension':['FileExtension'], 'ViewsLifeTime':['ViewsLifeTime'], 'ParentLink':['ParentLink'], 'FileType':['FileType'], 'IsContainer':['IsContainer'], 'SecondaryFileExtension':['SecondaryFileExtension'], 'DisplayAuthor':['DisplayAuthor'], 'ServerRedirectedURL':['ServerRedirectedURL'], 'SectionNames':['SectionNames'], 'SectionIndexes':['SectionIndexes'], 'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL':['ServerRedirectedEmbedURL'], 'ServerRedirectedPreviewURL':['ServerRedirectedPreviewURL'], 'RefinableString06':['RefinableString06'], 'UIVersionStringOWSTEXT':['UIVersionStringOWSTEXT'], 'RefinableString04':['RefinableString04'], 'RefinableString03':['RefinableString03'], 'RefinableString01':['RefinableString01'], 'RefinableDate00':['RefinableDate00']};
```

Then i used *SearchQueryToolv2.5* to see whether result for item i'm debugging javascript on actually have crawled/managed properties like *RefinableDate00* ... and it does.

When i display properties of *ctx.CurrentItem* in chrome javascript debug I see that there are my defined properties, but all are empty.

I also refreshed *Result Types* page both in site collection administration and site administration for site where i use search and display templates.

I'm think it worked before and just stopped, as I don't see  why I would put something that does not work to the production enviroment.

How to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **SharePoint admin center** > **search** > **Manage Search Schema** > **Managed Properties**, then click property name to view the details. In the Main characteristics section, make sure Searchable, Query-able, Retrievable **are checked**.

Also make sure your custom properties has been mapped to a managed property.

[image]

---

Also make sure after you have the right configuration, the properties has been crawled.

To request your tenant to instantly reindex e.g. a list, do the following:

- On the site, go to the list or library that you want to re-index.
- In the ribbon, click the Library tab or the List tab.
- In the Library ribbon, choose Library Settings, or,
- In the List ribbon choose List Settings.
- On the Settings page, under General Settings, choose Advanced
  settings.
- Scroll down to Reindex Document Library or Reindex List, and click
  the button. The content will be re-indexed during the next scheduled
  crawl.

I hope that gives you some help!

Comment: That is 100% NOT the issue as i already verified that the properties are crawled and indexed, and I even can use them in refiners.

Comment: @Evlo Ok, too bad that didnt help, I don't know what's causing the issue then. hope you find the cause...